# How to turn on 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON' in sqlalchemy migration script or configuration file for sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, alembic

In a suitable sqlite version, we can enforce foreign key constraint by 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON'. However user can not log in a database every time when making a connection. So I wonder how can we make it working in a migration script in sqlalchemy/alembic? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Foreign Key Support](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support) from SA SQLite documentation:

```
import sqlite3

from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    if type(dbapi_connection) is sqlite3.Connection:  # play well with other DB backends
       cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
       cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
       cursor.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Van, I will do test.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no logins.

To enable foreign keys in a script, just add the `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` command to that script.

Comment: Thank you. This is true that I need to add this code in some place. But the problem is how to add it. I will test.

Answer (score 0):

In an Alembic migration script you can use raw SQL to turn on foreign key support like this:

```py
def upgrade():
    from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
    session = Session(bind=op.get_bind())
    session.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;')
    session.commit()
    # Actual migration logic would follow.
```

Comment: This doesn't work as sqlite doesn't store this information in the file. Its based on connection. Reference: https://sqlite.org/forum/info/c5dc50f61b88c587

Comment: @ComproPrasad **it works during the alembic migration script**. Yes, the setting does not persist after the migration script finishes.