# SQLite PRAGMA foreign_keys with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I need to change the value of PRAGMA foreign_keys to 'off' before I do some operations, but then I would like to turn it right back 'on'.

Ultimately, I have only just gotten familiar with the ORM and havent had much time to get dirty with SQLAlchemy Core. When I import my Declarative modules, there is an import that makes sure my global engine has been started. Beyond that, I dont touch engines/pools/sessions.

I found this reference: [How to turn on 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON' in sqlalchemy migration script or configuration file for sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712381/how-to-turn-on-pragma-foreign-keys-on-in-sqlalchemy-migration-script-or-conf)

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()
```

I could just stick this in my global engine configuration, and use a switch to PRAGMA on or PRAGMA off...

```
    if self.enforceDBFK:
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    else:
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF")
```

How do you 'unlisten' the event (that seems cleaner)?

Any other suggestions on how to do this.

Note from SQLite docs on PRAGMA foreign_keys:

> foreign key constraint enforcement may only be enabled or disabled
>   when there is no pending BEGIN or SAVEPOINT

---

**Related Subtopic:**
On a second note, once I have the PRAGMA figured out, can I still use SQLAlchemy ORM instances to work on the tables (with foreign_keys=OFF)? SQLAlchemy doesn't enforce key integrity itself does it? How can I make SQLAlchemy also ignore foreign keys temporarily?

I just need to update a bunch of rows, but until the updates are completed as a group there will be broken/overlapping references all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we don't have an explicit API for event "removal" at this time though this is a feature that will eventually be available.  So you'd need to create a single event that itself turns itself on and off based on a flag, seems like that's what you've already worked out.

Comment: And just to clarify: Since this event happens on a new connection, what is the quickest way to force a new connection? `session.commit()`? I would like to do this from as high up as possible.

Comment: if you have NullPool in use then sure