# Dialect-specific sqlalchemy configuration

Tags: sqlalchemy

When using sqlalchemy with multiple dialects, just adding dialect-specific configuration such as [sqlite's foreign key support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13719230/1626632) or postgres' server_side_cursors poses a problem, because all other dialects will not understand the configuration or events. For instance:

```
# applying postgres configuration to a sqlite3 database fails
>>> sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite3:///test.sqlite3", server_side_cursors=True)
...
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'server_side_cursors' sent to create_engine(), using configuration SQLiteDialect_pysqlite/NullPool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

However, sqlite does not need this configuration, because it automatically streams results. Similarly postgres does not need to enable foreign key support, because that's the default.

How can I apply this dialect-specific configuration in a way, that does not break other dialects? Is there some sqlalchemy facilitating this branching? Is there something better than `isinstance` tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a created `engine`, one should branch on either `engine.dialect.name` (being `sqlite` or `postgresql` here) or `engine.dialect.driver` (being e.g. `pysqlite` or `psycopg2`). So the foreign key support should branch on `engine.dialect.name == "sqlite"` since it works with all drivers, but the `server_side_cursors` setting should branch on `engine.dialect.driver == "psycopg2"`, because other drivers for Postgres do not support this setting.

Thanks to nosklo on Freenode#sqlalchemy for the pointer.