# Flask Migrate "ValueError: Constraint must have a name"

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have created a flask migrate script, however, when I run the upgrade function, I get the following error:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 6378428b838a, empty message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "migrate.py", line 22, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 417, in run
    result = self.handle(argv[0], argv[1:])
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 386, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 95, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 280, in upgrade
    command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 298, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 173, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations/env.py", line 96, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "migrations/env.py", line 90, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 846, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 518, in run_migrations
    step.migration_fn(**kw)
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/migrations/versions/6378428b838a_.py", line 23, in upgrade
    batch_op.create_foreign_key(None, 'organisation', ['organisation'], ['id'])
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 119, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/operations/base.py", line 325, in batch_alter_table
    impl.flush()
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/operations/batch.py", line 106, in flush
    fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/slatifi/git/StaffTrainingLog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/operations/batch.py", line 390, in add_constraint
    raise ValueError("Constraint must have a name")
ValueError: Constraint must have a name
```

I have seen other people with the same error and they simply added `render_as_batch` to the `env.py`  file. I did this but I still get the same error. Any thoughts?

Note: This is the modification I made in the `env.py` file:

```py
with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args,
            render_as_batch=True
        )
```

This is the upgrade script created by the migration:

```py
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
    
    
# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '2838e3e96536'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None
    
    
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    with op.batch_alter_table('user', schema=None) as batch_op:
        batch_op.add_column(sa.Column('organisation', sa.String(length=5), nullable=False))
        batch_op.create_foreign_key(None, 'organisation', ['organisation'], ['id'])
    
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
    
    
def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    with op.batch_alter_table('user', schema=None) as batch_op:
        batch_op.drop_constraint(None, type_='foreignkey')
        batch_op.drop_column('organisation')
    
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The other answers show how to configure Flask to **use named constraints in the future**, but that doesn't solve the problem of ***dropping*** **existing unnamed constraints** in Alembic migrations. To handle any existing unnamed constraints, you need to also define the naming convention in the migration script, as explained in the [Alembic docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/batch.html#dropping-unnamed-or-named-foreign-key-constraints).

For example, suppose you're trying to do a migration that adds `ON DELETE CASCADE` to an existing foreign key in your `test` table. If you've followed one of the other answers (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62651160/470844) and added the `naming_convention` to the Flask init script, then `flask db upgrade` will generate something like this:

```py
def upgrade():
    with op.batch_alter_table('test', schema=None) as batch_op:
        batch_op.drop_constraint(None, type_='foreignkey')
        batch_op.create_foreign_key(batch_op.f('fk_test_user_id_user'), 'user', ['user_id'], ['id'], ondelete='CASCADE')
```

Note that while the `create_foreign_key` call uses a constraint name (i.e. `fk_test_user_id_user`), the `drop_constraint` call still uses `None` as the constraint name, which will cause `ValueError: Constraint must have a name` error in this question's title.

To fix that, you need to edit the migration to use the `naming_convention`, and replace the `None` with the generated constraint name. For example, you'd change the above `upgrade` to:

```py
naming_convention = {
    "ix": 'ix_%(column_0_label)s',
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
}

def upgrade():
    with op.batch_alter_table('test', schema=None, naming_convention=naming_convention) as batch_op:
        batch_op.drop_constraint('fk_test_user_id_user', type_='foreignkey')
        batch_op.create_foreign_key(batch_op.f('fk_test_user_id_user'), 'user', ['user_id'], ['id'], ondelete='CASCADE')
```

(In this example, you'd also need to disable SQLite foreign key support while running the migration script, e.g. using the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67163386/470844), to avoid the batch migration itself triggering a cacading delete. The problem is documented [here](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/batch.html#dealing-with-referencing-foreign-keys).)

Answer (score 18):

This is normal because SQLite3 doesn't support ALTER tables.

You can pass the `render_as_batch=True` during the instantiation of Flask-Migrate like this :

`migrate = Migrate(app,db,render_as_batch=True)`

Don't need to modify the `env` file of Flask-Migrate.

In addition, to totally avoid the problem for your futures migrations, you can create a constraint naming templates for all types of constraints to the SQLAlchemy metadata, and then I think you will get consistent names.

See how to do this in the [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#using-custom-metadata-and-naming-conventions) documentation. I'm copying the code example from the docs below for your convenience:

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

convention = {
    "ix": 'ix_%(column_0_label)s',
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
}

metadata = MetaData(naming_convention=convention)
db = SQLAlchemy(app, metadata=metadata)
```

Comment: I tried this as well but it still doesn't work - I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us the upgrade method from the migration file ?

Comment: I have updated the original question to include the above. Thanks for your support

Comment: @Saif: if you still get the same error after following this answer, you might need the additional changes in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66920329/470844) that let you handle existing unnamed constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Flask-Migrate helps to avoid code references to `declarative_base` or modifying the `env.py` file.
For apps with app factory, split the metadata assignment and the `db` initiation between the `extensions.py` and `__init__.py` files.

**extensions.py**:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

metadata = MetaData(
    naming_convention={
    "ix": 'ix_%(column_0_label)s',
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
    }
)

db=SQLAlchemy(metadata=metadata)
```

**__init__.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

from config import ...
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from extensions import db

...

def create_app(): 
    app = Flask(__name__,
                template_folder='../app/templates')

    app.config.from_object(config[...])
    config[...].init_app(app)
    
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    ...
    
    from .templates.main import main

    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app
```